# Is there a way to extend a cordova-plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to extend cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. Is there a standard way of customizing the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` is open source, and can be forked to your heart's content. If you're looking for a standard API, the Cordova docs do have a plugin development guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/

Comment: I think the desire to extend a plugin vs forking it is to continue to receive updates (enhancements and bug fixes) to the original.